# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in binomial cofficient dynamic programming

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that calculates (N choose R) using dynamic programming but I get an array out of bounds exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at BinomialCoefficients.method5(BinomialCoefficients.java:127)
    at BinomialCoefficients.main(BinomialCoefficients.java:50)
```

I am using a 2 dimensional array. Here is my code,

```
protected static long method5(long lN, long lR)
{
    long lArray[][] = new long[(int) (lN+1)][(int) (lR+1)];

    for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++)
    {
        lArray[i][0] = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++)
    {
        lArray[i][i] = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j <= i; j++)
        {
            lArray[i][j] = lArray[i-1][j-1] + lArray[i-1][j];
        }
    }
    /*for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(String.format("%5d", lArray[i][j]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }*/
    return lArray[(int) lN][(int) lR];
}
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you see any error? What is `j <+ i`?

Comment: oh, that was a typo. but I'm getting error at this line lArray[i][i] = 1;

Comment: Please add the error message in your question by editing it.

Comment: I did, and I changed something in it and now the error message is at this line: lArray[i][j] = lArray[i-1][j-1] + lArray[i-1][j];
@A.L

Comment: Same error or different? The error you're getting is obvious. You're attempting to access an array element outside the bounds of the array; don't do that.

Comment: I'm getting this error now, which is at the line I mentioned above:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at BinomialCoefficients.method5(BinomialCoefficients.java:136)
 at BinomialCoefficients.main(BinomialCoefficients.java:50)

Comment: Looks like you start with `i=0` and then do `i-1`; that's `-1`...

Comment: I changed to 1, and still getting an error but instead of -1, I'm getting a 7. My input is (10, 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the indexing error has already been corrected. But will point out that you're allocating a square array when you only need one row. You're also not taking advantage of symmetry. Consider something like this:

```
public class Binomial {

  public static long n_choose_r(int n, int r) {
    r = Math.min(r, n - r);
    long [] a = new long[r + 1];
    a[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      if (i <= r) {
        a[i] = 1;
      }
      for (int j = Math.min(r, i - 1); j > 0; --j) {
        a[j] += a[j - 1];
      }
    }
    return a[r];
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(n_choose_r(6, 4));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code looks suspicious

```
for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++)
    {
        lArray[i][i] = 1;
    }
```

considering lArray was initialized using two potentially different values:

```
long lArray[][] = new long[(int) (lN+1)][(int) (lR+1)];
```

I think you should have an inner loop here, such as:

```
   for(int i = 0; i <= lN; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<=lR; j++)    {
            lArray[i][j] = 1;
        }
   }
```